# JSON Object volley Post request - unable to hit server - rails local url bound to address 192.168.0.3

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, android-volley

The following event is triggered on a button click in Android, and is intended to make a post request to the rails server with params. The same code seems to be working in the past, not sure, what went wrong now.
On Debug, the cursor/control moves from creating JSONObject - js, to JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest( ...), and then to queue.add(jsonObjReq); 
Following error message shows up:- 
Message in Android studio monitor -  D/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: ShoppingCartActivity

Any/All suggestions are welcome.

Code here :-

```
bCheckOut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.0.3:3000/shopping/cart_items";

                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ShoppingCartActivity.this);
                final String access_token = "sWbxDJrF6SrB+DdWXLavoBz2LjiA5QCns5S6DMb7N4rDTWuHfcVYQ/1HxwHOq2fw7xXU4pXAjFw==“; //test purposes.
                Log.d(TAG, "Shopping cart item list: " + " Shopping cart items . " + LOGIN_URL);
                JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonobject_one = new JSONObject();

                    jsonobject_one.accumulate("variant_id", "4217");
                    jsonobject_one.accumulate("quantity", "1");

                    JSONObject jsonobject_TWO = new JSONObject();
                    jsonobject_TWO.accumulate("authenticity_token", access_token);
                    jsonobject_TWO.accumulate("utf8", "tick");
                    jsonobject_TWO.accumulate("name", "Rakesh");

                    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();

                    jsonobject.accumulate("requestinfo", jsonobject_TWO);
                    js.accumulate("authenticity_token", access_token);
                    js.accumulate("utf8", "tick");
                    js.accumulate("name", "Rakesh");
                    js.accumulate("cart_item", jsonobject_one);

                    //js.accumulate("Parameters", jsonobject);

                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST,LOGIN_URL, js,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                                //msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                                //hideProgressDialog();
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        //hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                }) {

                    /**
                     * Passing some request headers
                     */
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        return headers;
                    }
                };
                //ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
                queue.add(jsonObjReq);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting a response to this question, as the issue as has been resolved. Actually, restarting/rebooting the system and Android studio did the trick. I closed the application from the device, closed Android studio, and closed/restarted the whole system. 
Restarted the rails server at the specific ip address, and launched the application again, and the request was being successfully posted from the android device to the Rails server. Posting, since, if someone else happens to face the same issue or seem stuck, it might help. Thanks.